# 'ModSecurity: Error reading request body' when an AJAX request is sent from IE

Tags: php, ajax, apache, internet-explorer

I'm sending an ajax request using jquery as follows:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "lastMessageIndex.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {room: $("#room").val()}
        }).done(function(data){
            lastMessageIndex = data;
        });
```

I've tested this in my development environment and it works, I'm getting the expected response from the server, and the script goes on and the webapp works in general. But when I've uploaded it to my remote server, it doesn't, and in the apache2 error.log file I'm seeing the error:

`[Sun Oct 28 10:42:46 2012] [error] [client 44.46.23.50] ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Connection reset by peer [hostname "www.mysite.com"] [uri "/ie/IEGetMessages.php"] [unique_id "UI1ujNBx6w4AACW5MkkAAAAF"]`

This might not be the actual cause of the problem. I wouldn't mind having errors on the log if I'll be getting the response from the ajax I suppose to. It should be a number e.g. '4' and what I'm getting is a long string: "warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/tom/mysite.com/lastMessageIndex.php on line 11"

---

OK, while I was editing this I solved my problem. it's stupid actually, in my dev env, the mySQL database name has a capital letter, on the prod. env it's all lower case.

sorry for the unnecessary mess.

Comment: Have you googled the error message? There seems to be useful information when searching `ModSecurity: Error reading request body`

Comment: @Pekka: Who says that the error message is the problem? Isn't it the problem that on the development machine the error is not given?

Comment: No, I forgot to mention this so I'll edit the question now. The problem is that unlike in my development environment, I'm not getting the expected response from the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. You don't see that error on your development server because you have not installed Mod_Security on it. Install it, take over the same configuration as from the remove-system and you should see that error on your development system, too.